# Generate documentation from ABI json

Tags: abi, documentation

Is there a tool to generate readable documentation given a ABI json file? For example let's say I have this simple ABI:

```
[
{
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "retrieve",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "num",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "store",
    "outputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
}
]
```

This ABI only has two actions and it's easy to navigate. But if you work with large ABI's it's hard to find what you are looking for. I feel there has to be something but I just haven't found it. Something like https://swagger.io/docs/ for API's. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
"type" - "constructor", "function", "event"
"name" - method or event name
"inputs" - list of method or constructor parameters
"outputs" - list of return values for method (for functions)
"stateMutability" - special modifiers: view, nonpayable, etc. (for functions or constructor)

Оptionally:
"constant" - true/false (for functions)
"payable" - true/false (for functions or constructor)
"anonymous" - true/false (for events)
```

Comment: Yes, something like that! Do you know any tools?

Comment: My brain and fingers :-)